# How many ways can 10 coins be chosen?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A cashier’s till has a large number of pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters. In how
many ways can 10 coins be chosen from the till?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/251177/115823

Answer (score 4):

Assume there are at least ten of each coin in the till. Then you want the number of non neg integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$ where $x_i>=0$ which you can count with stars and bars.

Comment: See theorem 2 with n=10 k=4 here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29

Comment: Why is the answer not 4^10?  There are four ways to choose a first coin, four ways to choose a second coin, ..., four ways to choose a tenth coin.  Isn't this 4^10?

Comment: $4^{10}$ would count a set of coins made of 2 dimes and 8 pennies more than once, for example. (Bonus question:how many times?)

Comment: after writing out some Ds and Ps and noticing a pattern, I'd say the answer to your bonus question is 1+2+3+...+9 = 45

Comment: I forgot to tag you.  I got 45 for your bonus question.  I'm proud of myself.

Answer (score 1):

A generating function will also get you the same result and help you see it a little bit better if stars and bars doesn't make sense (though stars and bars is the easy way, once you see it).

We consider pennies for the moment. Note that $x^{i}$ says that we select $i$ pennies. So we consider selecting no pennies, selecting one penny, etc., which gives us the formal power series:

$$f(x) = (1 + x + x^{2} + ...) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i} = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

The number of ways to choose nickels, pennies, and dimes is the same, so we consider $(f(x))^{4} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{4}}$. And we want the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the expansion (give us $10$ coins).

Note that:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{4}} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{4 + i - 1}{i} x^{i}$$

So the coefficient of $x^{10}$ is $\binom{4 + 10 - 1}{10}$, as given by the stars and bars solution.